# SQL Greater than, Equal to AND Less Than

Tags: sql, select

I want to create a query like the following, But im unsure of how to code it correctly, 
I want it to return all bookings within 1 hour of a StartTime, Here is what i came up with:

```
SELECT BookingId, StartTime
FROM Booking
WHERE StartTime <=> 1.00
```

Is the possible? or Is there a way round it?

Everything ive found on the web hasn't been about using  Greater than,  Equal to and Less Than all in the same query.

Comment: You do mean 1 hour either side of a specified time don't you?

Comment: If a person is either older than you (GREATER THAN), your age (EQUAL TO), or younger than you (LESS THAN), that person could be any *living* person on the planet (or any *dead* person if you want to define ages for the dead).

Comment: if anyone hasn't noticed, or if they are confused, the OP has the `<` and the `>` switched around

Answer (score 15):

Supposing you use sql server:

```
WHERE StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GetDate())
                    AND DATEADD(HOUR, 1, GetDate())
```

Comment: `StartTime` checks with 2 hour gap. FYR: `select DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GetDate()) beforeAnHour, getdate () CurrentTime, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, GetDate()) AfterAnHour `

Answer (score 10):

If start time is a datetime type then you can use something like

```
SELECT BookingId, StartTime
FROM Booking
WHERE StartTime >= '2012-03-08 00:00:00.000' 
AND StartTime <= '2012-03-08 01:00:00.000'
```

Obviously you would want to use your own values for the times but this should give you everything in that 1 hour period inclusive of both the upper and lower limit.

You can use the GETDATE() function to get todays current date.

Comment: Just was about to ask if an AND would work. Thanks for your speedy reply

Comment: @user1081326 The AND would work but I suggest you use the between statment as shown in the other 2 answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @starttime datetime = '2012-03-07 22:58:00'

SELECT BookingId, StartTime
FROM Booking
WHERE ABS( DATEDIFF( minute, StartTime, @starttime ) ) <= 60
```

Answer (score 3):

Somthing like this should workL

```
SELECT BookingId, StartTime
FROM Booking
WHERE StartTime between dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()) and getdate()
```