# How to use greater or less than sign in C# MySQL update statement

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to set expiry status of a particular item in the database through my C# Winforms application.

So far I've tried this:

```
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("update items set Expiry = 'Yes' where ExpiryDate > "+ DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()+");",connection);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I'm having issues with it

Comment: Could you provide the issues you having with it?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610361/sql-greater-than-equal-to-and-less-than

Comment: Add your `DateTime` as a parameter, not as string concatenation for many reasons but the most obvious one here is you will forget to add single quotes around the value. In the future describe the `issues` you are having by providing the Exception and it's details (yes, this code will throw an Exception at runtime). See also [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your `DateTime` as a parameter, not as string concatenation for many reasons but the most obvious one here is you will forget to add single quotes around the value. In the future describe the `issues` you are having by providing the Exception and it's details (*the code in the OP will throw an Exception at runtime*).

```
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE items SET Expiry = 'Yes' WHERE ExpiryDate > @today", connection);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", DateTime.Today); // if you want time use DateTime.Now
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

The code above assumes that [items].[Expiry] is of type `Date` or `DateTime` in your table definition (schema).

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of your command object when you are done with it!